# Any barriers to selling an app with an HTML5 interface on iOS and Android platforms?

Tags: android, ios, html

I am considering creating an app that involves writing a proprietary interactive, stand-alone HTML5 graphical interface which communicates with a native back-end (Objective-c or Java).  My worry is that using HTML5 for a custom look and feel would block me from selling it on Android or Apple stores.

Does anyone know if Apple or Google would reject a request to sell an app that uses a custom HTML5 graphical interface?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are talking about writing your own webview (in the case of Android and whatever it is on Apple), then I don't see why they should object to it. There are other apps out there that do this.

If you are talking about setting up a HTML5 web page on a server somewhere and have that behave as a native application, the question then is why you want to go through Apple or Google to sell it. Your customers will be able to view the page and install a link on their home screen. You could probably wrap a thin browser essentially linking to a HTML5 page and sell that on Google Market or iPhone App store.

Comment: Yes, I am planning to write a WebView and not have a thin client that displays a website.

Comment: Yes that should be fine. The only thing that Android seems to have a policy against is pornography, I'm sure Apple probably does too. Besides that I think you can make your app do whatever you want and sell it on their store.